# Certificates Basic Constraint's Path Length

Tags: path, certificate, constraints

Is having a Path Length of 0 and None the same thing for Basic Constraint's of a CA type? To clarify, does a path length of 0  mean that the CA can issue no certificates while a path length of none mean that it can issue an infinite amount of certificates?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Taken from [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-39), section 4.2.1.9:

> A pathLenConstraint of zero indicates that no non-self-issued intermediate CA certificates may follow in a valid certification path.  Where it appears, the pathLenConstraint field MUST be greater than or equal to zero.  Where pathLenConstraint does not appear, no limit is imposed.

I.e. a `pathLenConstraint`of 0 does still allow the CA to issue certificates, but these certificates must be end-entity-certificates (the CA flag in BasicConstraints is false - these are the "normal" certificates that are issued to people or organizations).

It also implies that with this certificate, the CA must not issue intermediate CA certificates (where the CA flag is true again - these are certificates that could potentially issue further certificates, thereby increasing the `pathLen` by 1).

An absent `pathLenConstraint` on the other hand means that there is no limitation considering the length of certificate paths built from an end-entity certificate that would lead up to our example CA certificate. This implies that the CA could issue a intermediate certificate for a sub CA, this sub CA could again issue an intermediate certificate, this sub CA could again... until finally one sub CA would issue an end-entity certificate.

If the `pathLenConstraint`of a given CA certificate is > 0, then it expresses the number of possible intermediate CA certificates in a path built from an end-entity certificate up to the CA certificate. Let's say CA X has a `pathLenConstraint` of 2, the end-entity certificate is issued to EE. Then the following scenarios are valid (I denoting an intermediate CA certificate)

```
X - EE
X - I1 - EE
X - I1 - I2 - EE
```

but this and those scenarios with even more intermediate CAs are not

```
X - I1 - I2 - I3 - EE
...
```

Comment: So how do you say that a certificate can issue No certificates?

Comment: @Rory, you do this by making sure the certificate is NOT a CA certificate (i.e., set the cA attribute to false and ensure the keyCertSign bit in the key usage extension is NOT asserted).

Comment: Can the intermediate certs I1, I2 etc define there own pathLenConstraint?

Comment: @mR_fr0g, yes they can.Obviously, then can only make the restriction stronger, and not weaker.

Comment: yes, think @Rory pointed out a valuable question. creating a certificate with constraints and policies doesn't stop some person from using it to create dependent certificates. The constraints and policies should be handled through a proper certificate management system to enforce such restrictions such as validity periods, key usage, CPS, policies etc.

Comment: @LasithaMD If the certificate basic constraints section is marked critical and has the CA false flag set then nobody else can use that certificate to sign other certificates. If someone tried that it would fail during validation. Creating a CA certificate with the basic constraints section marked as critical and the CA flag set to true with the pathlen set to 0 is sufficient to prevent any certificate that CA signs from being able to act as a CA as well.